# SimRank in networkx is not running

Tags: networkx

When I run the command `s = networkx_addon.similarity.simrank(G)`, it is showing no module named networkx_addon ? Kindly suggest exact method how to run simrank using networkx or anaconda ? SimRank is not working properly in python.

Comment: Do you have a module installed that is named `networkx_addon`?

Comment: I tried to install. But unable to have networkx_addon modulue.

Comment: There is a `simrank` included in the soon to be released networkx distribution.  https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.similarity.simrank_similarity.html  You might try using it.  You'd need to install version 2.4, which is still not finalized.

Comment: Specifically, what went wrong when installing `networkx_addon`?

Comment: The reason I ask is that I have the impression you expect `networkx_addon` to automatically be there with `networkx`, and you're perhaps running into trouble importing it.  But it is an independent piece of software.  You will need to download it onto your computer before you can import it.  [it may be I'm misunderstanding your trouble].

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am facing the same problem using networkx_addon